# Typescript Express wont start listening in docker

Tags: node.js, docker, express, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to start a express server in docker, but it wont start listening, last message i get on screen is "Almost there"

Code of server:

index.ts

```
import express from 'express';
import dotenv from "dotenv"
dotenv.config()

const PORT = process.env.PORT

const app = express();

console.log("Almost there"); #also tried printing ${PORT}, works fine
app.listen(parseInt(PORT!), "0.0.0.0", () =>{
    `Started listening on port: ${PORT}`
});
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16 #tried various versions, won't budge
RUN mkdir -p /opt/app
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY . .
RUN yarn
EXPOSE 5000
CMD [ "npx", "ts-node", "index.ts" ]
```

docker-compose:

```
...
  backend:
    build:
      context: backend
    environment:
      PORT: 5000;
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

and finally package.json:

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "author": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.19",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "ethers": "^6.7.1",
    "express": "^4.17.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  }
}
```

I tried changing various versions of node, changed few versions of express, tried changing ts-node to tsx. Everything works fine on my pc, just doesn't start listening on that port inside docker

Comment: You forgot the `console.log( ... )` around the template literal in your callback function.

Comment: Also `parseInt(PORT!)` and `PORT` could be different. You'd do well to move the `parseInt` call to when you assign the value to `PORT` in the first place.

Comment: yes, i was waiting for that message to appear but it never did... Thank you @Quentin!
I wrote PORT! because of typescript, and it's message:
Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case closed...
While I had more stuff in the code, I'd always get http connection error to the container, than I added the "Started listening on port" and started changing stuff. I guess I had fixed my own problem, but waited for the message to appear in the logs..
I just opened one get endpoint and it's working... Sorry everyone =(